# Blackberry 10 Debug token - How long does an App stay on the phone?

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I can't find any documentation online, but when using Momentics IDE, when an APP is Ran/Debugged etc while your PC is connected to a phone...

**How long does this App remain on the blackberry?**

Answer (score 1):

**[Found in Blackberry SDK Documentation.](http://developer.blackberry.com/air/documentation/using_debug_tokens_ms_2010854_11.html)**

```
> Debug tokens are valid for ** 30 days **. When a debug token expires, the
> BlackBerry 10 OS no longer allows unsigned applications to run.
```

Answer (score 1):

An application running on the phone under a debug token will, as you found, only run until the debug toke expires. Itw will also only run while the device is in development mode. Development mode will automatically turn off on reboot or after 10 days.

The application itself will remain on the phone until removed.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, a debug token is valid for 30 days. However, you have the possibility to renew the debug token (once it's expired or before). If you renew it, you can run your application any time you want. Just be sure the token is valid.

When your token has expired, your application and its data are still on the device. You just can't launch the application anymore. If you renew the token, everything's gonna work again.

Development mode is needed to upload or renew a token and upload your application, but not needed anymore after that.